# String prints nothing

Tags: c, string, pointers, heap-memory

First, I know the use of malloc in this instance is poor practice; I am just curious as to why the following code doesn't work (logically, there are no compile or runtime errors)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//function to remove n number of characters from replicated string
char* remove_beginning(int n, char a[], int size)
{

int i;
char *p=malloc(size-(1+n));
for(i = n ;i < size-1; i++)
   {
     p[i] = a[i];  
   }

return p;

}



int main(){


char *str = "123456789";
char *second = remove_beginning(5, str, strlen(str));

printf("%s\n", second);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: In what way(s) does it not work?

Comment: It doesn't print anything

Comment: i think p[i] should be p[i-n]. Also, don't forget the null at the end.

Comment: Suggest avoiding using parameter name `size` when string length is passed.  Or call function with `remove_beginning(5, str, strlen(str) + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p[i] should be p[i-n] and you need to copy the null also:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//function to remove n number of characters from replicated string
char* remove_beginning(int n, char a[], int size) {
  int i;
  char *p=malloc(size-(n-1));
  for(i = n ;i <= size; i++) {
     p[i-n] = a[i];  
  }

  return p;
}


int main(){
  char *str = "123456789";
  char *second = remove_beginning(5, str, strlen(str));

  printf("%s\n", second);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code still fails to allocate memory for the terminating `0`/`NUL`/`'\0'`/null. Also **please** at least in answers properly indent the code.

Comment: It should be `size-(n-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the loop body and malloc in your function

```
char *p=malloc(size-(n-1));
for(i = 0 ;i <= size - n; i++)
{
    p[i] = a[i+n];
}
```

Comment: Even without null, shouldn't it print (albeit with potential garbage at the end)?

Comment: This code copies `n` elements from the `n`th on. This is not what tis OP is longing for.

Comment: As per your code the resulting string is always n char long although it should be size-n long.

Answer (score 1):

When removing beginning of a string can also be done with strncpy :

```
char tmp1[20] = "123456789";
char tmp2[20];
strncpy(tmp2, tmp1 + 5, 4);
```

I know it doesn't directly answer your question but I post it to show a "better" way of removing beginning of a string. `strncpy` can be used to copy a complete string, a beginning or end of a string.

Comment: Nice answer! Although, yes; not the one I was looking for :p